# Use sql query in str_replace

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, mysqli

I have a code for getting post title like this:
`$content = str_replace('%title', $post->post_title, $content );`

I'd like to use my own title from database.
I wrote this code:

```
        global $wpdb;
        $mycontent = $wpdb->get_var(
            'SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = '.$post->ID.' AND `meta_key` = \'my_seo_title\';'
        );
        $content = str_replace('%my_seo_title', $mycontent , $content);
```

**Does it make a security problem?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: What you are trying to do is really dangerous: Very easy to hack. See the "duplicate" I linked for how to SQL without the security risk

Comment: This is NOT how you use SQL.  You might need more help

Comment: which mysql driver you are using  PDO  .. mysqli ?.. you could do what you need  using a bining param

Comment: @norbert-van-nobelen I've used your link to edit my question. **Does my coding make a security trouble?** (`$wpdb` is for wordpress sql connection)

Comment: So, you're trying to replace `%my_seo_title` with the value of a custom field called `my_seo_title`?

Comment: Yes, concatenating user accessible data with SQL can lead to the mentioned SQL injection. Someone could add a `"; SHOW TABLES;`  for example by hacking your `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it have security issue?

In the unlikely event that your `$post` object gets replaced with something else (and at that point I'd consider the website's security as already compromised), the attacker could replace the value returned by `$post->ID` with a malicious query string (a.k.a. [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

To avoid that, as everyone else already pointed out, you should escape your query using the [prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method from the `$wpdb` object:

```
$mycontent = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s;",
        array( $post->ID, 'my_seo_title' )
    )
);
```

Out of curiosity, why are you manually retrieving the meta value from the database when we already have the [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function (which does the whole security check automagically for you)? I mean, you could replace your code with:

```
$mycontent = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_seo_title', true );
```

... and forget about writing queries by hand and/or making them secure (when not necessary).

Comment: Thanks a million @cabrerahector . I was in a wrong way (thinking of retrieving is necessary when the data is in another table) ; Your code code worked very well .